# Google Maps API v3 BrowserIsCompatible

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm updating some older code that used the v2 API for Google Maps. On domready, it would use a statement like

```
if(google.maps.BrowserIsCompatible()){
// load the map
}
```

Now that I'm loading the Google Maps API v3, I get an error

*google.maps.BrowserIsCompatible is not a function*

I've read a ton of threads in the Google v3 api groups, but haven't found a clear answer of what the new function is called or how to reference it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*GBrowserIsCompatibile* didn't make it into the version three API, so you will have to [write this code yourself](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/567079450fb3d897/73f1281204c9e057?lnk=gst&q=GBrowserIsCompatible#73f1281204c9e057).

[Here is a list](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#browsersupport) of the browsers supported by v3.

Comment: thanks cannonade! seems odd they'd drop this but I'm sure they had a good reason.

Comment: @julio Yeah I am not sure about that. They removed a few things that weren't core maps functionality from v3 (like the Http request wrapper stuff). I have a friend at Google, I'll ask her next time I see her :).

Comment: the list is not quite correct - **google api v3 seems to work in IE 6.0.**

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent of this method in V3 [as of Google's V2 to V3 migration doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3#obsolete_code).

Instead, an efficient way to achieve this test is:

```
if (window.JSON) {
    // load google maps api async (so google.maps object is available for further use)
}
```

That's because all the [browsers that Google Maps API V3 support](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#browsersupport) share that same particularity : they are the first versions (by their vendor) that **supports JSON natively**. 
See this [screenshot taken from caniuse.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkS8O.png):

[image]

Exceptions:

Firefox 3.0 and BlackBerry Browser 6 don't support JSON but are supported by Google Maps API. So the rule above will exclude both, which is an acceptable drawback for such a simple test (compared to a user-agent-sniffing-based code)

Notice:

this test doesn't apply to 'google.maps' object but at script load time.
This prevents cases (e.g IE6) when the script is successfully loaded but 'google.maps' object unusable.