# Google maps API - how to check browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cross-browser

How do I check if google API v3 supports current browser? I need some function to do something like this:

```
if (!FUNCTION_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR()) {
    alert('Sorry, your browser is not supported by Google Maps.');
    return;
}
```

I wasn't able to find appropriate function [in the API v3 reference](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html)

Comment: I think the Maps API does that by itself already. At least V2 did

Comment: @Pekka, but what if I want a custom message?

Comment: you may be out of luck because the API complains before you have a chance to suppress it. I don't know for sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is currently not available in v3 (it is called `GBrowserIsCompatible()` in v2). There is an issue filed in the [gmail-api-issues tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2223).

**Edit by OP:** Also look here: [Google Maps API v3 BrowserIsCompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517491/google-maps-api-v3-browseriscompatible)

Comment: thank you bunting! That's a real shame! Especially when they don't support IE6, this would be needed!