# IE and GMap API 2 wrapper bug

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Since november 19 google map stop supporting version 2, instead they provide a wrapper for API v3 that should work with old implementation. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/ for more information... My old websites works in Chrome but not in firefox and IE(11 but I think there's problem in more version) Here's a sample website : http://www.lotavendre.com/

Anyone know what I can do? Do I need to rewrite my js? Why is it working in Chrome?

Comment: What is not working? With Firefox I see a map, markers and after clicking on a marker I get to a kind of details-page. Beside that: I still would migrate my application because Google might shut down the wrapper in the future.

Comment: On my side I get "GIcon is not defined" and "google.maps.BrowserIsCompatible is not a function" javascript errors and I'm using firefox 25.0.1 on win 8.1

Comment: Regarding the second error, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517491/google-maps-api-v3-browseriscompatible

Comment: I think this is a temporary issue - I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099944/google-maps-v2-to-v3-api-wrapper-working-in-chrome-but-not-in-firefox-ie, however right now, at least FF works again.

Comment: @sigma0815 It seems to work now, do you still have any problems?

Comment: @VinnyG nope - most samples from: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/ are working now too.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone know what I can do?

Port your code to the [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics)

> Do I need to rewrite my js?

You should have rewritten it to use the v3 API a while ago.